# Excel VBA to hide rows based on another cell selection can't get code to work

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, which I am trying to use to hide specific rows based on a result of another cell.  (there is a formulae in this cell which concatentates the result from a series of other cells into a letter - A, B, C, etc.)

However there must be something wrong in my code because I cannot get it to work - nothing changes irrespective of what I change for the target cell.

This is my code - I am using Excel 2016 if that's of any relevant

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "G26" Then
Select Case Target.Value
        Case "A": Rows("45:45,47,53:57,77:78").Hidden = True
        Case "B": Rows("40:52,77, 78,80,,85").Hidden = True
        Case "C": Rows("43,45,46,47,49,53:57,61:83").Hidden = True
        Case "D": Rows("40:49,53:57,77,78,80").Hidden = True
        Case "E": Rows("53:57").Hidden = True
        Case "F": Rows("43,46,47,50:57").Hidden = True
        Case "G": Rows("43,45:47,50:53").Hidden = True
        Case "FG": Rows("43,46,47,50:57").Hidden = True
        Case "H": Rows("41:42,44,45:57,77,78,80").Hidden = True
        Case "I": Rows("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:82").Hidden = True
        Case "HI": Rows("41:42,44,45:49,53:57,77,78,80").Hidden = True
        Case "J": Rows("41:57,63,67,72,74:83").Hidden = True
        Case "": Rows("40:85").Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Address` property returns absolute address, so output will be `$G$26` instead of `G26`

Comment: I can't get any form of a list of rows within `Rows()` to work. I can only get one at a time e.g. `Rows("2:4").Hidden = True` works but `Rows("2:4,6:10").Hidden = True` doesn't - I get a 'Type Mismatch'  error when it hits that line.

Comment: @AntiDrondert he has compensated for this by using (False, False) after Target.Address - that is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(False, False) = "D25" Then
Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Select as appropriate": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case "USA - Breen Road": Range("45:45,47:47,53:57,77:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "USA - Conroe": Range("40:52,77:78,80:80,85:85").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "USA - Lafayette": Range("43:43,45:47,49:49,53:57,61:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Europe - Aberdeen": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Europe - Gateshead": Range("53:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Middle East - Dubai": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Middle East - Saudi Arabia": Range("43:43,45:47,50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "middle East - All": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - Loyang": Range("41:42,44:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - Tuas": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Singapore - All": Range("41:42,44:45:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Case "Far East - Perth - Australia": Range("41:57,63:63,67:67,72:72,74:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Range().EntireRow.Hidden` instead of `Rows().Hidden` to allow lists of rows in the format you want

I.e. replace your

`Rows("xyz").Hidden = True`

with

`Range("xyz").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

I used find and replace on your original code to produce the following (note I also deleted a double comma ,, in one of the lines) - Try this:

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "G26" Then
Select Case Target.Value
        Case "A": Range("45:45,47:47,53:57,77:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "B": Range("40:52,77:78,80:80,85:85").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "C": Range("43:43,45:47,49:49,53:57,61:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "D": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "E": Range("53:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "F": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "G": Range("43:43,45:47,50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "FG": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "H": Range("41:42,44:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "I": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "HI": Range("41:42,44:45:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "J": Range("41:57,63:63,67:67,72:72,74:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Select Case Range("G26").Value
        Case "A": Range("45:45,47:47,53:57,77:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "B": Range("40:52,77:78,80:80,85:85").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "C": Range("43:43,45:47,49:49,53:57,61:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "D": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "E": Range("53:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "F": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "G": Range("43:43,45:47,50:53").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "FG": Range("43:43,46:47,50:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "H": Range("41:42,44:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "I": Range("40:49,53:57,77:78,80:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "HI": Range("41:42,44:45:49,53:57,77:78,80:80").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "J": Range("41:57,63:63,67:67,72:72,74:83").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case "": Range("40:85").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Listing `47` instead of `47:47` and etc will throw an error.

Comment: I suspected but didn't test - have rectified

Comment: Am I right in saying that this should not be in any module but sit in the sheet object itself?

Comment: If that is the case then I still cannot get anything to work at all - nothing is happening in my spreadsheet at all (It is saved as an xlsm file type)

Comment: Yes it should be in the worksheet code... Have you tried placing a break marker on the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` line to make sure the event is firing? - or perhaps try adding this line straight after the `Private Sub...` line : `MsgBox(Target.Address)` and see if the correct cell address is showing.

Comment: Thanks I will try this later and let you know if it works

Comment: OK really struggling here, when I enter the MsgBox command I get the target address as being the cell I have just added information into and not the one which will change based on the selection I make.

For example if I change cell C26, this should make G26 go from blank to an A, which would then I hope fire the private sub to start hiding the cells in the code above.  But while cell G26 does show an A, nothing else happens

Comment: I see the problem, you're always testing if G26 has changed and if you change C26 then the event fires only for that cell, doesn't matter if the value in G26 changes due to that change, it'll just test for C26! I have pasted a 2nd block of code in my answer that has removed the testing for G26 changes and just checks the value of G26 after any other cell change.

Comment: OK got it to work, but had to change the code completely so that rather than a range of cells which effected the target cell, I had one cell with a drop down list and used the drop down selections as my trigger.  Now works a treat.  here is my finished code